# Dynamic Pivot in sql 2012 , instead of value nulls are comming

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with design as below.

```
HIST_TIMESTAMP  datetime    Unchecked
HIST_TIMESTAMP_DST  char(1) Unchecked
TABLE_INDEX int Unchecked
HIS_CHANGED varchar(1)  Checked
QUALITY tinyint Checked
VALUE   real    Checked
```

I have data in my table as follow:

```
HIST_TIMESTAMP  HIST_TIMESTAMP_DST  TABLE_INDEX HIS_CHANGED QUALITY VALUE
2017-08-14 12:18:01.000 s   1   NULL    1   -3.927756
2017-08-14 12:19:01.000 s   1   NULL    1   -3.927756
2017-08-14 12:18:01.000 s   2   NULL    1   5.109651
2017-08-14 12:19:01.000 s   2   NULL    1   5.109651
2017-08-14 12:18:01.000 s   3   NULL    0   NULL
2017-08-14 12:19:01.000 s   3   NULL    0   NULL
2017-08-14 12:18:01.000 s   4   NULL    1   50
2017-08-14 12:19:01.000 s   4   NULL    1   50
2017-08-14 12:18:01.000 s   5   NULL    1   36.59948
2017-08-14 12:19:01.000 s   5   NULL    1   36.59948
2017-08-14 12:18:01.000 s   6   NULL    1   -122.7314
```

Total of 3744 Table index and data is storing every minutes for all table index

Now I want a pivot to convert my timestamp as columns, I tried using pivot TSQL 
code as follows:

```
use eta_user
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.HIST_TIMESTAMP) 
        FROM eta_user.ANALOG_HISTORY c 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 

set @query = 'SELECT TABLE_INDEX, ' + @cols + ' from 
        (
            select table_index
                , value
                , hist_timestamp
            from eta_user.analog_history 
       ) x 
        pivot 
        (
             max(value)
            for HIST_TIMESTAMP in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '
```

execute(@query)

But Output is having nulls , I don't know why. Screen of output is:

```
1   NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL
4   NULL    NULL
5   NULL    NULL
6   NULL    NULL
7   NULL    NULL
8   NULL    NULL
9   NULL    NULL
10  NULL    NULL
11  NULL    NULL
12  NULL    NULL
13  NULL    NULL
14  NULL    NULL
15  NULL    NULL
16  NULL    NULL
17  NULL    NULL
18  NULL    NULL
19  NULL    NULL
20  NULL    NULL
21  NULL    NULL
22  NULL    NULL
23  NULL    NULL
24  NULL    NULL
25  NULL    NULL
26  NULL    NULL
27  NULL    NULL
28  NULL    NULL
29  NULL    NULL
30  NULL    NULL
31  NULL    NULL
32  NULL    NULL
33  NULL    NULL
34  NULL    NULL
35  NULL    NULL
36  NULL    NULL
37  NULL    NULL
38  NULL    NULL
39  NULL    NULL
40  NULL    NULL
41  NULL    NULL
42  NULL    NULL
43  NULL    NULL
44  NULL    NULL
45  NULL    NULL
46  NULL    NULL
47  NULL    NULL
48  NULL    NULL
49  NULL    NULL
50  NULL    NULL
51  NULL    NULL
52  NULL    NULL
53  NULL    NULL
54  NULL    NULL
55  NULL    NULL
56  NULL    NULL
57  NULL    NULL
58  NULL    NULL
59  NULL    NULL
60  NULL    NULL
61  NULL    NULL
62  NULL    NULL
63  NULL    NULL
64  NULL    NULL
65  NULL    NULL
66  NULL    NULL
67  NULL    NULL
68  NULL    NULL
69  NULL    NULL
70  NULL    NULL
71  NULL    NULL
72  NULL    NULL
73  NULL    NULL
74  NULL    NULL
75  NULL    NULL
76  NULL    NULL
77  NULL    NULL
78  NULL    NULL
79  NULL    NULL
80  NULL    NULL
81  NULL    NULL
82  NULL    NULL
83  NULL    NULL
84  NULL    NULL
85  NULL    NULL
86  NULL    NULL
87  NULL    NULL
```

Table index count is correct but null is coming instead of value.
Anybody please help me how to correct the code to get the values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Select your @cols, does it have what you expect it to have?

Comment: Add `print @query` before execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the select of your pivot use 
         Cast( hist_timestamp as varchar(max))as hist_timestamp instead .

The hist_timestamp is getting converted to varchar in stuff query, hence its value changes to something like 'Aug 14 2017 12:18PM'. But the table data is available in the format of datetime- '2017-08-14 12:19:01.000'.So, for correct matching convert the select clause hist_timestamp to varchar as well.

```
 use eta_user
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.HIST_TIMESTAMP) 
    FROM eta_user.ANALOG_HISTORY c 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 

set @query = 'SELECT TABLE_INDEX, ' + @cols + ' from 
    (
        select table_index
            , value
            ,Cast( hist_timestamp as varchar(max))as hist_timestamp       
 from eta_user.analog_history 
   ) x 
    pivot 
    (
         max(value)
        for HIST_TIMESTAMP in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p '
```

Comment: Great!! Please upvote or mark as answered,if my answered has helped you :)

Comment: I am new here, can you please explain how to do that